# Executing Javascript code after loading refreshed page

Tags: javascript, onload

I have a Javascript file that is split into to two parts. The first part of the code ends by refreshing the current page. I would like to try to get the second part of the code to execute as soon as the page reloads, but I am having trouble finding a way to implement this. I pretty much want a way to do

```
window.onload = someFunction()
```

except that it activates the function after reloading the page due to the first part of the Javascript. Is there an effective way to do this?

Comment: Add Javascript at the end of page.

Comment: `window.onload = someFunction`?

Comment: A little bit more code can make the question a bit more clear .

Answer (score 3):

You could do that using Jquery.
This is executed on page loading

```
$(function() {
    callMyFunction()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

`document.onload = somefunction()` 
Instead . This will get executed immediately after the DOM loads .

You can also use the jQuery to do the same like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    somefunction();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to add query string value when refreshing, then read that value and act upon it.

You can use such code:

```
function ParseQueryString() {
    var result = [];
    var strQS = window.location.href;
    var index = strQS.indexOf("?");
    if (index > 0) {
        var temp = strQS.split("?");
        var arrData = temp[1].split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            temp = arrData[i].split("=");
            var key = temp[0];
            var value = temp.length > 0 ? temp[1] : "";
            result[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

window.onload = function WindowLoad() {
    var QS = ParseQueryString();
    var reloaded = QS["reloaded"];
    if (reloaded === "1") {
        //execute second part of code
    }
}
```

Then when reloading, redirect to same page adding `?reloaded=1` otherwise (if this flag is already raised) don't refresh the page again to avoid infinite loop.